# How to convert MATLAB MWArray to Bitmap with C# from MATBLAB .NET Compiler

Tags: c#, winforms, matlab

I searched and some a few examples but I did not get any idea even it seems to be a something relatively easy I hope someone can help

I have a very simple MATLAB function, taking a `string filePath` of an image and covert it to GrayScale using `rgb2gray(filePath)`

```
function I = ConvertToGrayScale(filePath)     
  RGB  = imread(filePath);
  I = rgb2gray(RGB);     
end
```

Then it got compiled to `dll` file using MATLAB Comiler with the class name `ImageProfessing` to have `ConvertToGrayScale.dll`.  No error, compiler gave the `dll`

In C# Winform, 
I included the 2 dlls:`MWArray` and `ConvertToGrayScale` as reference in my C#, the test image is loaded directly from `@"D:\\Caputure.PNG"` which is also displayed on `pictureBox1`, when user hits button `Convert to GrayScale`, the image is converted and displayed on `pictureBox2`

```
using MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays;
using CovertToGrayScale;
```

[image: WinForm]

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(@"D:\\Capture.PNG");
}

private void btCovertToGrayScale_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    ImageProcessing imageProcessing = new ImageProcessing();
    MWCharArray fileStringArray = new MWCharArray(@"D:\Capture.PNG");
    MWArray I = imageProcessing.CovertToGrayScale(fileStringArray);
    int[] dim = I.Dimensions;
    MessageBox.Show(dim.ToString()); // just to see what dim is
}
```

--->  I do not know how to convert `I` to `Bitmap` so I can display, save, or load to `MemoryStream`.  I checked `I` and it is not empty, it does contain data of the GrayScale image (using `I.IsEmpty` and `I.NumberofElements`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard approach for converting a byte array to a `Bitmap` in `C#` uses the [Bitmap(Stream)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z7ha67kw(v=vs.110).aspx) constructor overload as follows:

```
Byte[] data = ...;
Bitmap bmp;

using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data))
    bmp = new Bitmap(ms);
```

But this works only if your `data` array contains the whole image binary data, and not only pixels data. So things get a little bit harder in this case, since what you retrieve from Matlab is just an `height-by-width` matrix with pixels information. First, you have to convert the `MWArray` into a flatten `Byte[]`:

```
MWArray I = imageProcessing.CovertToGrayScale(fileStringArray);
MWNumericArray I_num = I.ToArray();
Byte[] I_bytes = (Byte[])I_num.ToVector(MWArrayComponent.Real);
```

Once you have the grayscale pixel data converted into the native `Byte` format, you must proceed as follows (`w` and `h` are two integers representing the respectively the width and the height of the image... you can assign their values from `I.Dimensions`):

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(w, h, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
ColorPalette cp = bmp.Palette;

for (Int32 i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
    cp.Entries[i] = Color.FromArgb(255, i, i, i);

bmp.Palette = cp;

BitmapData data = bmp.LockBits((new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height)), ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, bmp.PixelFormat);
Marshal.Copy(I_bytes, 0, data.Scan0, I_bytes.Length);
bmp.UnlockBits(data);
```

Comment: thank you very much but I got the error `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Requested range extends past the end of the array.'` when run your code.

Comment: I wrote this code blind eyes because I dont't have the framework installed. Can you -at least- make the effort to tell me on which line it happens?

Comment: It happens with the  `Marshal.Copy(I_bytes, 0, ptr, bytes);`

Comment: there is no error return, it does give grayscale image but unexpected way - please see image http://i67.tinypic.com/2i7mozq.png

Comment: This is probably due to how the MWArray is converted to Byte[]. You have to check the order in which bytes are sorted along the scan lines.

Comment: Thanks - the image is  mirrored.